# Lendo arquivo inteiro

Tags: c++

Estou tentando ler um arquivo simples, que contem apenas duas linhas, mas o programa mostra apenas uma. O programa:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("file.lua");
    myfile >> str;
    cout << str << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return 1;
}
```

O resultado é:

> print(1)
>
> Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 0.044 s Press any key to
>   continue.

O arquivo contém:

> print(1) print("Hello")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta é a forma canónica de ler um ficheiro de forma sequencial em C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream ifs( "myfile.txt" );
    string line;
    while( getline( ifs, line ) ) {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Repara que antes de processar o conteúdo é efectuado uma validação, assegurando que não passamos o final do ficheiro.

Mais próximo do teu exemplo, e se quiseres ler o conteúdo do ficheiro de uma só vez para uma string, eu faria:

```
std::ifstream t("myfile.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();
....
```

Com o teu caso o problema é estar apenas a ler a primeira linha. Podes tentar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str, str2;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("file.lua");
    myfile >> str >> str2;
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Com seu primeiro exemplo, consegui fazer