# Criptografia não lê espaços

Tags: c++

Bom, estou tentando criptografar um arquivo de texto com o seguinte "programa":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void writeFile(char* filename, string str){
    ofstream f(filename);
    f << str;
}

string readFile(char* filename){
    string str;
    ifstream f(filename);
    f >> str;
    return str;
}
string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {
    char key[3] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'}; //Any chars will work
    string output = toEncrypt;

    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

    return output;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string encrypted = encryptDecrypt(readFile("file.lua"));
    cout << "Encrypted:" << encrypted << "\n";

    string decrypted = encryptDecrypt(encrypted);
    cout << "Decrypted:" << decrypted << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

O conteúdo do arquivo "file.lua" é:

> local a = ola

Mas o output do programa é:

> Encrypted:',2*/ Decrypted:local

Mas se ao invés de :

```
string encrypted = encryptDecrypt(readFile("file.lua"));
```

eu usar:

```
string encrypted = encryptDecrypt("local a = ola");
```

Funciona normal, e o output fica:

> Encrypted:',2*/q*clk,=* Decrypted:local a = ola

Comment: Olá Gabriel. Como você pode notar pela resposta que recebeu, o seu problema é essencialmente o mesmo [da sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60682/lendo-arquivo-inteiro). Se você não entendeu o que ocorre, poderia ter pedido mais detalhes lá na pergunta original ao invés de abrir outra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o operador `>>` elimina todos os espaços em branco (quebra de linha, espaços, tabulações). Ou seja, no caso você está pegando apenas a primeira palavra, até o espaço. O ideal seria substituir no método `readFile` a linha:

```
f >> str;
```

por está sequência de comandos:

```
stringstream buffer;
buffer << f.rdbuf();
str = buffer.str();
```

Isso lerá todo o arquivo, incluindo todos os espaços em branco.

Comment: Perfeito. E também não esquecer de dar #include <sstream>